# $m(\alpha E)=\alpha m(E)$ ? for every Lebesgue measurable set and $\alpha >0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let's consider a Lebesgue measurable set $ E \subset \mathbb R$. And let's consider a positive constant $\alpha>0$. I want to know if it's always true $m(\alpha E)=\alpha  m(E)$. Clearly $m$ denote the Lebesgue measure.

At least in the case where $mE=0$ or $\infty$ it's true and also in the case of $ E=[a,b]$ but I can't prove it or disprove it. Please help me. In the case that the result it's true I want to see some proof, if it's not, please I want to see a general family of sets that have that property.

Comment: And then of course $m(\alpha E) = | \alpha | mE$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $|I_n|$ be a covering sequence of open intervals such that $m^*(E) \le \sum |I_n| \le m^*(E) + \epsilon$ where $m^*$ denotes outer measure.

Write each $I_n$ as $(a_n,b_n)$.  Define $\alpha I_n := ( \alpha \cdot a_n , \alpha \cdot b_n )$.  Clearly, $\{ \alpha I_n \}$ is a covering sequence of intervals for $\alpha E$, since $\alpha \cdot e \in \alpha I_n$ for some $I_n$.

Moreover:

$$m^*(\alpha \cdot E) \le \sum | \alpha I_n | = \alpha \sum |I_n| \le \alpha m^*(E) + \alpha \epsilon$$

$\epsilon$ is arbitrary so $m^*(\alpha \cdot E) \le \alpha m^*(E)$.

The reverse inequality follows by the fact that $\alpha^{-1} (\alpha E) = E$, so $m^*(E) \le \alpha^{-1} m^*(\alpha \cdot E )$ by the exact same proof as above.

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways of showing this.

One simple way is to take the linear transformation $f(x) = \alpha x$, and note that $\alpha E = f(E)$.
Then the change of variables theorem gives
$m (f(E)) = \int_{f(E)} 1 = \int_E (1 \circ f) J_f$, where $J_f(x) = |\det \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}| = \alpha$. Since $1 \circ f = 1$, we have $m(F(E)) = \alpha \, m(E)$, as required.

Alternatively, you could note that if $\{I_k\}$ is a countable cover of $E$ by intervals, then $\{\alpha I_k\}$ is a countable cover of $\alpha E$ by intervals,
ans similarly, if $\{J_k\}$ is a countable cover of $\alpha E$ by intervals, then $\{ \frac{1}{\alpha} J_k \}$ is a countable cover of $E$ by intervals. Since $l(\alpha I) = \alpha l(I)$ for intervals, it follows that the outer measure $m^*$ satisfies $m^* (\alpha E) = \alpha \, m^*( E)$, and hence it is true for $m$.

A third approach would be to note that the statement is true for intervals $I$, that is, $m(\alpha I) = l(\alpha I) = \alpha l(I) = \alpha m(I)$.

Any open set can be written as the disjoint union of a (well, at most) countable collection of intervals, hence if $U$ is open, we have $U = \cup_k I_k$, and $m (\alpha U) = \sum_k m(\alpha I_k) = \sum_k l(\alpha I_k) = \alpha \sum_k l(I_k) = \alpha \sum_k m(I_k) = \alpha m(U)$.

Finally, since $m$ is outer regular, for any measurable $E$ we have $m E = \inf \{ m(U) | E \subset U, \ \ U \text{ open} \}$. It follows that $m(\alpha E) = \alpha m(E)$ for any measurable set $E$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets of the line and let $m:M\to\mathbb R$ be the Lebesgue measure.

The functions $\mu:E\in M\mapsto m(aE)\in\mathbb R$ and $\mu':E\in M\mapsto am(E)\in\mathbb R$ are $\sigma$-additive measures.

It is trivial to check that $\mu$ and $\mu'$ coincide on the subring of $M$ of intervals. Since $M$ is the completion of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that subring, the usual theorems of extension of measures imply that $\mu=\mu'$.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove this using the definition of Lebesgue measure. We can define the Lebesgue outer measure as
$$
m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{n≥1}\ell (I_n)\middle|E\subset\cup_{n≥1}I_n\right\}
$$
and we note that $m(E)=m^*(E)$ for measurable sets $E$.

With that in mind: note that any set $A\subseteq(a,b)$ satisfies $\alpha A\subseteq(\alpha a,\alpha b)$ and that $\ell(\alpha(a,b))=\alpha \, \ell(a,b)$.  It follows that for any collection of sets $\{I_n\}_{n≥1}$ whose union contains $E$, we may state that $\{\alpha I_n\}_{n≥1}$ is a collection whose union contains $\alpha E$ and whose total length is $\alpha$ times longer.  For any set $A$ of real numbers, $\inf (\alpha A) = \alpha \inf A$.  The desired statement follows.